# Grails3 + mysql not creating table name and column name with camel notation

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.1

Actually i migrated grails2 to grails3.
but domain names are not properly binding with mysql db table.
For eg:

```
domainName is: EmployeeCompany
expected table name in mysql: employee_company
but its creating as with the name: EmployeeCompany
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting this property on application.yml (DataSource.groovy in grails 2):

```
hibernate { 
    naming_strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
}
```

Comment: Do grails3 have `DataSource.groovy` file?

Comment: in grails3 datasource.groovy is not there..but same property i added in application.yml, then it started wrking as per my requirement.